# magento custom from required-entry not working

Tags: validation

i have added few custom field in from with calss="required-entry"

to validate that field is required and show javascript error message it empty.

but it is now working am i missing something ?

below i link:
http://bellb2b.com/customer/account/create/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation classes work only inside a form. You put your elements outisde the `form`  tag.

Comment: no they are inside form tag

Comment: @saurav No they are not inside a `<form>` tag. I just ran this in the console `$('ncompanyname').up('form')` and I get `undefined`. The form tag closes after the email field.

Comment: yeah but when i view source i can see form tag at bottom

Comment: Then your markup is not valid. Try to make it w3c valid. Use this validator to identify the errors http://validator.w3.org/